# frank build fails on ld command

Tags: ios, cucumber, integration-testing, frank

I'm following the tutorial recommended on the Frank-Cucumber website (http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2012/06/24/writing-your-first-frank-test/), but once executing `frank build`, the build fails saying:

```
The following build commands failed:
    Ld Frank/frankified_build/2012\ Olympics.app/2012\ Olympics normal i386
(1 failure)
```

This clang error is present around the previous `ld` call:

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I'm using XCode 4.6.3, I have the command line tools installed, and I'm running the example application taken from GitHub.

What could be wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like using `sudo frank build --arch armv7s` fixes it.