# Frank Cucumber iOS 6 Black Screen

Tags: ios, cucumber, integration-testing, frank

I've tried to install Frank-Cucumber using the documentation provided (http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2012/06/24/writing-your-first-frank-test/), however I receive a black screen on the simulator every time I try to do a `frank launch`

From the groups it seems like more people are having this problem and there is no real answer posted. Resetting the content and settings from the iOS simulator did not fix this problem for me.

Is this a known problem? Are cucumber tests no longer possible in the iOS 6+ simulators?

I'm running this on iOS 6, Xcode 4.6, OSX Mountain Lion.

Any ideas?

*extra edit:* The iOS simulator gives back the following error: `The 'com.thunderkeybolt.2012olympics.frankified' bundle at (null) does not have an executable path. Please check the bundle's Info.plist file` when trying to run the default example from above (the app for the 2012 Olympics).

---

Frank output on `sudo frank build`: https://gist.github.com/shto/67c99aa8d0d1ecc2ae7a

Comment: Looking at your previous question, it looks like you got Frank to build by passing it --arch armv7s. However, the simulator only runs in i386. You need to get your project building in i386 for it to work in the simulator. Your previous question did not contain the actual error output by the linker. Posting the full build log would help in diagnosing that problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185129/frank-build-fails-on-ld-command

Comment: If I do put i386 as a valid architecture, when executing `frank build` I receive the following error message `Ld Frank/frankified_build/2012\ Olympics.app/2012\ Olympics normal i386`. (ld: file not found: Frank/frankified_build/2012 Olympics.app/2012 Olympics) That file is indeed not there. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I have Xcode 4.6, OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion). I just downloaded the project, ran `setup`, `build` and `launch` and I had no problems. No changes required. Do you have a valid wildcard ("Team") provisioning profile? Please add the whole `frank build` log.

Comment: @Sulthan Does your application support i386 as a valid architecture?

Comment: @Andrei I didn't do any changes to the example project, the i386 architecture was built by default.

Comment: @Sulthan Ok, the 2012 Olympics projects I downloaded didn't have i386 as a valid architecture.

Comment: @Sulthan Maybe it's a permission problem for me. Seems like running `sudo frank build` does most of the things fine, except that it still fails on one of the commands that frank build executes: `Ld Frank/frankified_build/2012\ Olympics.app/2012\ Olympics normal i386`

Comment: @Andrei Please try it with the clean git project and paste the `frank build` log here :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35345/discussion-between-andrei-and-sulthan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log it can be seen that the app is built by the beta of Xcode5.

This is a common problem when more than one Xcode version is installed. To fix it, there is a `xcode-select` command to choose the correct Xcode version for command line tools.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
```